# How to connect express server with a database in aws instance

Tags: mysql, express, server

I am making a server with express and typescript, but I cannot connect my server to a database that I have in an instance in aws, this is the server code:

```
import { createPool } from 'mysql2';
  export async function conectar() {
      const conectando = await createPool({
          host:'myIPInstance',
          port: 3306,
          user:'myuser',
          password:'mypass',
          database:'example',
          connectionLimit: 10
      });
      return conectando;
  }
```

and when I do a get to see the contents of a table I get the following error:

```
 (node:4704) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections 
  are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled 
  will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
  [1] events.js:177
  [1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  [1]       ^
  [1] 
  [1] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://3.13.108.243
  [1]     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
  [1] Emitted 'error' event at:
  [1] at /home/node_modules/mysql2/lib/pool.js:143:20
  [1] at /home/node_modules/mysql2/lib/pool.js:59: 18
  [1] at PoolConnection.<anonymous (/home/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:716:13)
  [1] at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:288:20)
  [1] at PoolConnection.emit (events.js:205:15)
  [1] at PoolConnection._notifyError (/home/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:212:12)
  [1] at PoolConnection._handleFatalError (/home/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:151:10)
  [1] at PoolConnection._handleNetworkError (/home/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:160:10)
  [1]     at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
  [1]     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8) {
  [1]   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  [1]   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  [1]   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  [1]   hostname: 'MyIpInstance',
  [1]   fatal: true
  [1] }
```

How could I fix the error, what do I need?

Comment: It looks like the IP you're trying to access doesn't exist or is not accessible. What you can do is try and open the DB's network and make it public. If you can confirm you can now access it, reconfigure it to make it secure.

Comment: In my instance I opened the corresponding port in the security group: MYSQL/Aurora TCP 3306 0.0.0.0/0